# Doing wrong in this fraction simplification?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, rational-functions

$$
\frac{5}{2x-3} - \frac{3}{(2x-3)^2}
$$

I have to simplify

So I had the minimun common multiple in

$$(2x-3)^2$$ which is $$(2x-3)(2x-3)$$

---

Then I divide the first fraction denominator by my term, then multiply it by 5, ends in 10x-15. Then I divide the second fraction's denominator by my term, ending in -3.

$$
\frac{10x-15-3}{(2x-3)(2x-3)}
$$

After making calcs, I end with:

$$
\frac{10x-18}{4x^2-12x-9}
$$

Which seems to be a completely different graphic in Geogebra.

Geogebra's Simplify function gives a very "unsimplified" result for my original formula.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The denominator should be $4x^2-12x+9$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only error is in the development of $(2x-3)^2$, which is
$$
(2x-3)^2=4x^2-12x\mathbin{\color{red}+}9
$$

Comment: So it was that simple..... thanks a lot!